# WPF Gmap.NET adding large amount of markers

Tags: c#, wpf, gmap.net

i'm using Gmap.NET with C# WPF, and i'd like to add a large amount of markers (~6k) on the map.
But i still can't make add them asynchronously, Map is always freezing and not responding at all, until all markers will not be added...
Here is my code sample:

```
private void MainMap_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainMap.Zoom = 12;

    LoadMarkers();
}

private async void LoadMarkers()
{
    await Task.Run(new Action(() =>
    {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 6000; i++)
            {
                Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
                    new Action(
                        delegate()
                        {
                            PointLatLng point = new PointLatLng(GetRandomNumber(55.0000, 55.7510),
                                GetRandomNumber(36.0000, 38.9999));

                            var currentMarker = new GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation.GMapMarker(point);
                            {
                                currentMarker.Shape = new MarkerTemplate(this, currentMarker,
                                    string.Empty);
                                currentMarker.Offset = new Point(-16, -32);
                                currentMarker.ZIndex = int.MaxValue;

                            MainMap.Markers.Add(currentMarker);
                            }
                        }
                        ));
            }
        }));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to design a cluster marker solution for GMap. Use the `Map_OnMapZoomChanged` event to hide/show markers accordingly.

With a bit of a work, you might be able to achieve a cluster like the [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering) one:

[image: GMap Marker Cluster]

Good luck! Don't forget to open-source it when you're done :)